# How to create excel VBA change log

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a change log for excel VBA. I want it to iterate through so that the each additional response is populated in the workbook as the additional rows. Please let me know if you have any insight into what is wrong with my code

```
    Dim streply As String
    Dim Today As Date
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim inglastrow As Long

    CurrentDate = Date

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        nextrow = lastrow + 1
        MsgBox lastrow
        MsgBox nextrow
    End With

    MsgBox lastrow
    streply = InputBox(Prompt:="Please type description of changes", Title:="Change Log", Default:="Brief Desc.")

    If streply <> " " Then
        Range("A" & nextrow).Value = Application.UserName
        Range("B" & nextrow).Value = streply
        Range("C" & nextrow).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        Range("D" & nextrow).Value = Date
    End If

    Set lastrow = Nothing
    Set nextrow = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: it's not clear what problems do you have with your code?

Comment: Sorry its not iterating through the code. For some reason Last row is stuck at 5 and nextrow is stuck at 6

Comment: I don't see any part of code where it's supposed to iterate..can you explain in details what result do you expect? what code should do?

Comment: The way that I want it to work is 1)User sees input screen enters information 2)VBA finds last row & adds one 3)Last row is populated with new value 4)Next row is populated with the change log information

Comment: How is this code called? You don't show the start of your sub. Is this a "change_sheet" event?

Comment: I am still working with how this code is called. I might do a worksheet change or just use it a button. I want to get the functionality down first. To answer Simoco's question I thought that nextrow=lastrow +1 would allow me to iterate through the cells

Comment: sorry, it's still unclear what code should do:) As I undestood, 1) input box pops up and user enters description..2) this description writes in (lastrow+1) row. What should happened next?

Comment: After the user writes the response it should be populated in the next open row.

Comment: Is the only thing on this sheet the change log or are there other tables and bits of data that might get in the way?

Comment: Simoco is right, I just copied and ran your code as in the question and it works fine for me - I started with a blank sheet and tested it through row 30.  I ran it by selecting the function in VBA and clicking the "play" button.  How are you running it currently for your tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: silly mistake on my part, fixed now**

Instead of:

```
lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Try:

```
lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: That is returning the total number of rows in excel

Comment: @̶E̶d̶w̶a̶r̶d̶A̶r̶m̶s̶t̶r̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶I̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶s̶s̶u̶m̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶h̶e̶e̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ ̶l̶o̶g̶.̶ ̶ ̶I̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶c̶o̶r̶r̶e̶c̶t̶?̶   Actually, scratch that, fixed my mistake.  Try it now!

Comment: It is sticking on 15 and 16 as the last rows. It does not add new responses as a new row. Thanks for the help